# How to make my website mobile friendly - cant seem to fix with @media queries

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile

I tried using media queries as usual but i dont know what I'm doing wrong.
this is how it looks on desktop:
[Desktop]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIQbK.png
and here is what it looks on mobile :
[Mobile]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0JLP.jpg
.
when i comment out the .css file the margins disapear. i dont really know which @media queries to use here.
i want it to be same as the desktop.
triend to change the position and manually adjusting the margins. but nothing works well, first post here. i couldnt find answers on the internet for all day long, hope you could help! thank you in advance..
(it is on top of a video)

```js
// function([string1, string2],target id,[color1,color2])    
consoleText(['נשבר לכם המסך?', 'הטלפון נפל למים?', 'הטלפון אינו נטען?'], 'text', ['white', 'red', 'black']);

function consoleText(words, id, colors) {
    if (colors === undefined) colors = ['#fff'];
    var visible = true;
    var con = document.getElementById('console');
    var letterCount = 1;
    var x = 1;
    var waiting = false;
    var target = document.getElementById(id)
    target.setAttribute('style', 'color:' + colors[0])
    window.setInterval(function () {

        if (letterCount === 0 && waiting === false) {
            waiting = true;
            target.innerHTML = words[0].substring(0, letterCount)
            window.setTimeout(function () {
                var usedColor = colors.shift();
                colors.push(usedColor);
                var usedWord = words.shift();
                words.push(usedWord);
                x = 1;
                target.setAttribute('style', 'color:' + colors[0])
                letterCount += x;
                waiting = false;
            }, 1000)
        } else if (letterCount === words[0].length + 1 && waiting === false) {
            waiting = true;
            window.setTimeout(function () {
                x = -1;
                letterCount += x;
                waiting = false;
            }, 1000)
        } else if (waiting === false) {
            target.innerHTML = words[0].substring(0, letterCount)
            letterCount += x;
        }
    }, 120)
    window.setInterval(function () {
        if (visible === true) {
            con.className = 'console-underscore hidden'
            visible = false;

        } else {
            con.className = 'console-underscore'

            visible = true;
        }
    }, 400)
}
```

```css
#myVideo {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  #myVideo video {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    z-index: 0;
  }
  .console-container {
   font-size:4em;
    text-align:center;
    height:200px;
    width:600px;
     display:block;
     position:absolute;
    color:white;
     top:0;
      bottom:0;
      left:0;
      right:0;
      margin:auto;
      text-shadow: 
      2px 2px #ffffff,
      4px 4px #000000;
   }
```

```html
    <section class="banner embed-responsive-item">
        <video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
            <source src="https://mobilefixexperts.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/mobile-repair-experts-video.mp4"
                type="video/mp4">
        </video>
        <div style='direction: rtl;' class='console-container float-end'><span id='text'></span>
            <div class='console-underscore' id='console'>&#95;</div>
        </div>
        <a id="a" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg float-end" href="#" role="button">צור קשר</a>
        <!-- <h2 class="float-end display-1" style='direction: rtl;'>מה תרצו לתקן היום?</h2>
        <a id="a" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg float-end" href="#" role="button">צור קשר</a> -->
    </section>
```

the css code is :

```
.console-container {
   font-size:4em;
    text-align:center;
    height:200px;
    width:600px;
     display:block;
     position:absolute;
    color:white;
     top:0;
      bottom:0;
      left:0;
      right:0;
      margin:auto;
      text-shadow: 
      2px 2px #ffffff,
      4px 4px #000000;
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common problem I have faced it too.
The thing that is doing this is the large text, you may see that the website starts messing up when the large text touches the right side of the screen. So, the solution to tackle this problem is to make that text responsive means it should not touch the side it should become smaller so you can do like:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 425px) { //Note where it starts happening
   #text {
         font-size: 3em; //small than what it was before
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question you wannt to remove the margin on mobile/small screens?

This css will do it:
`@media screen and (max-width:500px) { body{margin:0;} }`

Comment: not working, if you will look at the second picture to get what i mean..

Answer (score 0):

Add `position: relative;` to your **banner** class and then you can use the media query you want.

```
.banner{
     position: relative;
   }
```